# unable to convert a list object into a data table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `JSON` object which i get from an ajax post call,which i am mapping it to my list of Customclass objects like below.

```
[ObjectFilter(Param = "postdata", RootType = typeof(List<ExportToExcel8020>))]
        public void ExportToExcel(List<ExportToExcel8020> text) 
        
{
  //List<ExportToExcel8020> rm = text.AsEnumerable().ToList();
  //DataTable UserDt = rm .ToDataTable();
  DataTable UserDt = text.ToDataTable();
}
```

This is how my list object looks,

[image]

Now I want this `generic list object` to be converted into a `datatable`,
i am trying to do this by using the below method. But i get an error which says

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...Domain.Common.ExportToExcel8020>' does not contain a definition for 'ToDataTable' and no extension method 'ToDataTable' accepting a first argument of type...
>
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List<...Domain.Common.ExportToExcel8020>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

            //Get all the properties
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                //Setting column names as Property names
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {
                    //inserting property values to datatable rows
                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            //put a breakpoint here and check datatable
            return dataTable;
        }
```

The reason i need it as a `datatable` is to use `openxml` and export an `excel` file.

Is there something wrong with my code? or is my apporach itself is wrong?

Comment: Looks like  you are trying to create an extension method. You need to do `public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to write an extension method. the method signature needs to have `this` as a keyword to the first parameter which then specifies the type you are extending (and passes in the instance of the object when the extension method is called). try

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
```

as the method signature.

Comment: Thanks @skintkingle, that worked. I would like to add a little more info, The method should also be written in a static class as this  is an extension method.